# Resolving cross platform error?

Tags: ios, macos, visual-studio, xamarin

I am attempting to build iOS apps in C# in Visual Studio with the help of the Xamarin software.  My question is, is there any other solutions for resolving the build host connection between my Mac and PC?  I have successfully downloaded the Xamarin software on the PC but on my mac i cant install Xamarin because it has the 10.6.8 software but Xamarin needs 10.7.0 at the least.  I have already installed Xcode successfully as well.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you will need to update your Mac build host machine to 10.7 in order to use the cross platform building solution provided by Xamarin.

This is because one of the key requirements is that you have [Xamarin.iOS](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/mac/) installed on the Mac build host which, as you mentioned, requires 10.7.